# Portlet Configuration window does not open

Tags: java, spring, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc, liferay-6.2

Following dependencies issues into a MVC spring Liferay portlet, I tried to rebuild it from scratch.

Most of it is now OK but the portlet preferences.
It used to work on the former portlet but does not on the built from scratch portlet.
I have correctly  set Liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<configuration-action-class> com.<packagename>.<subpackagename>.config.ConfigurationActionImpl</configuration-action-class>

Same results with default class:
<configuration-action-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
```

This part works as the "configuration" option is now available when I click the right top corner of the portlet.

Portlet.xml includes :

```
<init-param>
        <name>config-template</name>
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/config/config2.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
```

I also copied the  former jsp that was working correctly into the new project.
It does load properly. When I click "configuration", all of the System.out.println are correctly displayed into the console output), but the setup window does not appear and thus the html elements are not displayed.
All I get is the portlet page attempting to load a window but it never opens.

Are there any other files included that I might not have re-setupped properly?

Comment: I think I somehow corrupted the stored portlet preferences.
Is there a way to default them (without using the portlet configuration window as it does not open anymore)?

Comment: I just realize that if I click top right corner and click "look and feel" or "export / import", the corresponding popups do not load either.
The other features are OK though (minimize / maximize / remove).
Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Narrowing a bit more, sounds completely insane to me but:
My main view does not load look and feel / configuration and import export popups.
My other jsp do load them correctly!!
What could change the behaviour in my main jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was caused by this :

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet">
```

When I remove this from the jsp, everything works again.
thx to myself ;)
Hope it wil save somebody else's time...